# Is Cassandra counter column strongly consistent?

Tags: cassandra

Is Cassandra counter column strongly consistent ? Will it have issues like lost updates or dirty read?

Answer (score 0):

No, they are not strong-consistent.  They are also not idempotent and don't handle retry logic gracefully.

If you're planning to use them, I'd give this article by Paddy Byers a read:
https://ably.com/blog/cassandra-counter-columns-nice-in-theory-hazardous-in-practice

Comment: ... then what is point of having it? Just give you a syntax sugar so that you can do:
Update Table Set column=column+1 where ....?

Comment: @Stan Yeah, it's really meant as a tool for approximation.